# VBA Array of Sheets with a range, loop through cells and change value of separate column

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, range, declare

The goal is to look through Column A in all Sheets in the array. If "CASH" is found in a cell in Column A, replace Column D of that same row With "USD".

I am hitting an error with the array.range. I realize I can't declare it as is but not sure what to do from here. I will likely his a snag with the loop as well, open to suggestion there too.

Thanks

```
    Sub test()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim SCAFI, ILB, IILB, MMA, IMBD, SCAEQ, IMEQ, IREA, IMSC, ExclSecFI, ExclSecEQ As Worksheet
Dim FIFindCASH, FIFindCASHRng As Variant

Set FIFindCASHRng = Sheets(Array("SCA FI", "ILB", "IILB", "MMA", "IMBD", "Excluded Securities FI")).Range("A:A")


Set SCAFI = Sheets("SCA FI")
Set ILB = Sheets("ILB")
Set IILB = Sheets("IILB")
Set MMA = Sheets("MMA")
Set IMBD = Sheets("IMBD")
Set SCAEQ = Sheets("SCA EQ")
Set IMEQ = Sheets("IMEQ")
Set IREA = Sheets("IREA")
Set IMSC = Sheets("IMSC")
Set ExclSecFI = Sheets("Excluded Securities FI")
Set ExclSecEQ = Sheets("Excluded Securities EQ")

For Each Sht In FIFindCASHRng
    If Cell.Value = "CASH" Then
        Cell.Value.Offset(0, 3) = "USD"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test the next code, please:

```
Sub testIterateChangeVal()
 Dim wb As Workbook, Sht As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use here the needed workbook

 For Each Sht In wb.Worksheets
    Select Case Sht.Name
        Case "SCA FI", "ILB", "IILB", "MMA", "IMBD", "Excluded Securities FI"
            lastRow = Sht.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 1 To lastRow
                If Sht.Range("A" & i).value = "CASH" Then
                    Sht.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 3) = "USD"
                    'or
                    'Sht.Range("D" & i).value = "USD"
                End If
            Next i
    End Select
 Next
End Sub
```